# cocos2d-x: Should I add cocos2d folder in my git repo?

Tags: git, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-4.0

I am new to cocos2d-x. Currently it's upgraded to 4.0

I tried to add files to my repo as first commit. I did some research, and I found out some added the cocos2d folder (library) in the repo, but some didn't. It's almost 300MB. Should I include this folder and it's file into my repo?

What is the best practice?

[image]
Thanks in advance.